# Is there an endpoint to get the configured public certificate in a Spring Security OAuth application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In a Spring Boot application that acts as Authorization Server with Spring Security Oauth, I have configured JWT and a key pair to sign the tokens.

Is there any existing endpoint that allows us to get the public certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: `/oauth/token_key`

In order to allow unauthenticated access we need to add this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    ...
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous()");
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already wrote a self-answer, but maybe a reference could help, see [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html):

> **JWT Tokens**
>
> [... ]The tokens are signed by default, and the Resource Server also has to be able to verify the signature, so it either needs the same symmetric (signing) key as the Authorization Server (shared secret, or symmetric key), or it needs the public key (verifier key) that matches the private key (signing key) in the Authorization Server (public-private or asymmetric key). The public key (if available) is exposed by the Authorization Server on the `/oauth/token_key` endpoint, which is secure by default with access rule "denyAll()". You can open it up by injecting a standard SpEL expression into the `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer` (e.g. "permitAll()" is probably adequate since it is a public key).

and

> ```java
> @Override
> public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
>     oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')").checkTokenAccess(
>                 "hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");
> }
> ```
>
> In this example we are configuring both the `/oauth/check_token` endpoint and the `/oauth/token_key` endpoint (so trusted resources can obtain the public key for JWT verification). These two endpoints are protected by HTTP Basic authentication using client credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.well-known` discovery endpoint to get details about all the endpoints, signing algorithms, etc.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/.well-known`, returns a 404, is this the right path?

Comment: Every authorization server has a `.well-known` discovery endpoint. It might not exactly be this url. Better to check the documentation and find correct one. Something similar to https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfig

Comment: Actually I'm not using OIDC but OAuth2, and can't find any information about it for this kind of Spring OAuth2 authorization server...I appreciate the info anyways.